# How to configure WCF service instance (self hosted, per session instance)

Tags: .net, wcf

I have following problem: I have self hosted WCF service (per session). This service instances, which are automatically created by ServiceHost, need some additional configuration which is not part of the config file. In other words, I need to use an object of class xyz within the service instance. This object is created and configured in the self host container. So I need to pass it on the service instance object. How to do that??

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research and investigation: I have solved the problem.

- Implement a class which implements IInstanceProvider interface
- Implement a class which implements Attribute and IServiceBehavior
- add this 'Behavior' to the ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors property

See [MSDN blog regarding issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider/)